# Send data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am developing an app for the iphone.The thing is that i want to send the values of longitude and latitude i get from the phone using javascript to a server commanding it to search for something.Do i have to read about cross domain stuff? How could this be done?
I know that i can use Ajax but it can serve me if i refer to the same domain.
For example how can i do this:
`$.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/',{lon:30})` and have my database searched for objects that have this longitude?
I don't want to do this:

```
$.post('/search/',{lon:30})
```

I use django on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called JSONP that is meant to solve this problem. You can read about it [here.](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) Its basically regular json with a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at the below link:

http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/3f93834df24114b9/9c6596da9bedd4b2?q=#9c6596da9bedd4b2

Answer (score 0):

JSONP or "serverside AJAX proxy" are your two options if the target server is in a different domain than your application.